# Cloud Build API

Tags: google-app-engine

We received mail from google about activating cloud build api before April 2020
We follow , easy instructions to activate the service, select our project then go continue. 
We receive a strange, I think server side,  error:

[image]

is anyone getting  same problem ?

Comment: I just followed those instructions and did not get that error.

Comment: Hi @giorgio could you please provide the link for the documentation that you followed? And besides that, the exactly step that you faced this error?

Answer (score 0):

You can try from cloud shell. Try below command:

```
gcloud services enable cloudbuild.googleapis.com
```